# Is there a function whose Dirichlet series and whose Taylor series are the same?

Tags: complex-analysis, taylor-expansion, dirichlet-series

That is, does there exist a sequence $\{a_n\}_{n\ge 1}\subset\mathbb{C}$, such that $$
\sum_{n\ge 1} \frac{a_n}{n^z} = \sum_{n\ge 1} a_n (z-r)^n
$$
for some $r\in\mathbb{C}$? Or perhaps shift there's a shifted version:
$$
\sum_{n\ge 1} \frac{a_n}{n^z} = \sum_{n\ge 0} a_{n+1} (z-r)^n
$$
Is is possible for a function's Dirichlet series and Taylor series to have the same coefficients?

---

One can attempt to expand the Taylor series of the Dirichlet series term-by-term, but then you find an infinite system of equations for the coefficients $a_n$, but in general if such systems are not triangular, solving them is difficult, so there might be an easier way.

Comment: $\frac{1}{n^z} = e^{-z \log(n)} = \sum_{k=0}^\infty \frac{(-1)^k z^k \log^k(n)}{k!} = 1 + \cdots$ so the termwise Taylor expansion of the Dirichlet series can't converge, each term contributes $1$ to the sum.

Comment: Not after multiplying by the coefficient $a_n$, or if you expand the series around a different point from $z=0$, it could be easier (or harder) to converge.

Comment: This is true, but it adds the condition to the Dirichlet series that $\sum_n a_n$ converges, which is not true for a general Dirichlet series as far as I know.

Comment: I am aware of that. I am asking if there is *any* example where the Taylor series equals the Dirichlet series. Also, if you expand the series at $2$ (or any point with real part bigger than 1) instead of at $0$, you don't need summability of $a_n$.

Comment: $a_n=0$ is such a sequence.

Comment: @Mason true but not what I'm asking about. Is there a non-degenerate case? i.e. with some $a_n \ne 0$ for $n>1$?

Comment: The equation is $\forall n, a_n-\frac1{n!}\sum_m a_m m^{-s}(-\log m)^n  = 0$. . It might not have any non-zero $O(n^{s-1-\epsilon})$ solution because $1/n!$ decreases very fast so that the equation becomes close to $a_n=0$.